# How do I write this function in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, window-functions

I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
     the_date date,
     user_id  int,
     pop      REAL,
     hip      REAL,
     lop      REAL,
     cop      REAL
 );
```

I want to write a function `foofunc()` that references the previous row and returns a value based on the following logic:

```
function foofunc() returns numeric as $body$
begin
-- # calculate  (current_row.hip - current_row.lop) as val1 for current row
-- # calculate  abs(current_row.hip - previous_row.cop) as val2
-- # calculate  abs(current_row.lop - previous_row.cop) as val3 
-- RETURN max(val1, val2, val3)
end;
$body$ language plpgsql
```

I want to be able to call the function `foofunc()` like this:

```
SELECT foofunc()
from foo 
where the_date between date1 and date2 
and user_id=some_id;
```

How do I implement `foofunc()`?

Comment: Define the order. What is "previous"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "previous" is defined by `the_date` ..

You don't actually need a plpgsql function for that. A plain query with a window function does the job, and much faster, too:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT *
          ,lag(cop,1,0::real) OVER (ORDER BY the_date) AS p_cop
    FROM   foo
    WHERE  the_date <= <date2> -- don't exclude earlier rows yet
    AND    user_id = <some_id>
    )
SELECT GREATEST (
       hip - lop
      ,@(hip - p_cop)
      ,@(lop - p_cop)
       )
FROM   x
WHERE  the_date >= <date1>
ORDER  BY the_date;
```

---

If you actually need a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foofunc(_user_id int, _date date)
 RETURNS real AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

RETURN (
    WITH x AS (
        SELECT *
              ,lag(cop,1,0::real) OVER (ORDER BY the_date) AS p_cop
        FROM   foo
        )
    SELECT GREATEST(
         hip - lop
        ,@(hip - p_cop)
        ,@(lop - p_cop)
        )
    FROM   x
    WHERE  the_date = _date
    AND    user_id  = _user_id
    );

END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT foofunc(1, '2012-07-21');
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Apart from the verbose/terse PostgreSQl documentation (most of which does not provide useful examples), is there a link or a book that you can recommend me to read in order to be able to write queries such as this my self and to increase my knowledge of SQL?. For example `WITH` and `GREATEST` are new keywords to me, and I still don't fully understand how to use window functions, which means I will simply copy and paste the code you provided, without really truly understanding how it works.

Comment: I learned most from the excellent manual and trying. Well, and the basics at university. You can skim SO - try the search. There are lots of useful examples. Or [dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). I alone have posted dozens of answers using window functions. I have been working with PostgreSQL for close to 15 years now, don't expect to learn it all in a day.

Comment: there are fundamental parts of documentation http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-select.html